# How to create a duplicate of my Angular App (with firebase)

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

I have an app created using angular cli. It is basically a barcode app with login system and i want to create a copy of it and run the copy finally giving me two seperate apps. My this app is also connected to firebase hosting and firestore so i fear that copying it might result in an error. I dont know the correct steps to follow

**STRUCTURE OF MY APP (NAME: LOGINPAGE)**

[image]

**VERSION DETAILS OF CLI**

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.6
Node: 12.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.7
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.803.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.803.6
@angular-devkit/core               8.3.6
@angular-devkit/schematics         8.3.6
@angular/cdk                       8.2.0
@angular/cli                       8.3.6
@angular/fire                      5.2.1
@angular/material                  8.2.0
@angular/material-moment-adapter   8.2.0
@angular/pwa                       0.801.3
@angular/service-worker            8.2.9
@ngtools/webpack                   8.3.6
@schematics/angular                8.3.6
@schematics/update                 0.803.6
rxjs                               6.4.0
typescript                         3.5.3
webpack                            4.39.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I have Base app A Which is maintained in git. I need a copy of that app named B for a client. The following are the steps I follow:

- create a [[group](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/)] in Gitlab
- fork the baseapp A project into the group
- go to the forked project and change the name and url etc. as you need for app B in the project settings
- transfer the project from the group to your user (in settings).

Once this is done, you can make changes as you need to your copy app and maintain changes separately independent of your original app.

I hope this solves your issue.